# Install a python module in the same directory as the main handler

Tags: python, aws-lambda, python-ldap

Hello I want to install a module named python-ldap locally in the same directory as my main so that it could be zipped and uploaded as a standalone function. The reason is AWS Lambda doesn't support installing this module (but i have installed it successfully on AmazonLinux). So I'm hoping i can install the module in an AmazonLinux instance and zip it so it runs on any instance. If its possible that is.

For example purposes i have a folder deploy-ldap with a single lambda_function.py inside.
The lambda_function.py simply imports the module like so:

```
import ldap

def main():
   print("Success")
```

What I tried so far:

There are some resources on this suggesting to copy a single .so file but it didn't work for me and resulted in an error where another .so.2 file is being requested

Furthermore i tried installing the module with `pip install python-ldap -t .` but this also resulted in an error: "Unable to import module 'lambda_function': No module named '_ldap'"

All input appreciated, thank you. ^^

Comment: see https://medium.com/@sct10876/run-python-ldap-on-aws-lambda-131ac703f10c

Comment: This solution didn't work for me. After adding the .so file to the project and testing the Lambda i still got an error requesting for another .so.2 file

Answer (score 0):

The `import python-ldap` is incorrect because [module names](https://pep8.org/#package-and-module-names) in Python shouldn't contain dashes. The correct import as in the [examples](https://www.python-ldap.org/en/python-ldap-3.3.0/bytes_mode.html#porting-recommendations) should be:

```
import ldap
```

Then to make it available in the environment of your AWS Lambda function, you should follow the same steps as documented in [Deployment package with dependencies](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/python-package.html) which consists of the following steps:

- Prepare the file containing the code
- Perform `pip install python-ldap`
- Deploy the code along with the installation to AWS Lambda

Comment: Thanks for the input, this one is my fault, I do in fact have it as `import ldap` in my code just replicated it wrong here sorry about that. And as I said i tried installing it in an AmazonLinux 2 instance and copying the files to Lambda but it didn't work. (I also tried making it with a Layer but still same error)